# c# resizing controls in splitcontainer

Tags: c#, splitcontainer

I have a splitcontainer with 2 panels.  In the first panel is a Treeview and a Datagridview in the other.

When I move the splitter, to be able to see more of the treeview, the Datagridview gets 'pushed' out of the wind

Comment: Well sure, what else would you expect?  Although admittedly I don't know what kind of wind is blowing.

Comment: :)  Somehow half my question got cut out!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Dock` property of the control in each pane to `Full`.

If you have multiple controls in a pane, you'll need to set their `Dock` or `Anchor` properties to achieve the behavior you want.

Comment: and if you have, say, a status strip docked bottom and a datagridview docked full, then 'send to back' the status strip to stop the DGV from covering it (I know, this isn't very intuitive)

Answer (score 1):

Minor point, but the dock style you want is `Fill`, not `Full`.